# Young adult series, cryosleep, crashed spaceship. People were turned to "swiss cheese" by worms

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

When I was in 6th grade I remember reading 2 or 3 books in a sci fi series.

From what I can remember a ship full of people (mostly teens) had crashed and awoken the main character and several survivors.

Some of the sleepers are eaten by space worms. It's set in the future where the rich could slightly alter their genes, like having "cat eyes" for instance.

I remember the survivors having to chop someone's leg off to stop the worms from spreading.

Comment: I think it may have been printed between 2000 and 2003

Comment: See OP confirmation comment below. Target is an unaccepted answer also confirmed by comment, but is already set up as the target of other closed duplicates.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are talking about the Remnants series, by KA Applegate. She also wrote the Animorphs and Everworld series. I used to love her when I was a kid!

Comment: You're absolutly right. Thank you very much. Now I can read them all.

Comment: If it's right, don't forget to +1 the answer and mark it as "best answer" :-) Another satisfied customer...